# Echo works, but return does not in php function

Tags: php, return, echo

I have the function below. It can echo the result just before the `return`, but it cannot return it (I get NULL).

Why it does not work, and what do I need to do to get it working?

```
class Config
{   
    public static function findKey($key, $array) {
        foreach($array as $item) {
            if(is_array($item)) {
                if(isset($item[$key])) {
                    return $item[$key];
                } else {
                    self::findKey($key, $item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help that I can get with this!

Comment: How are you using that code

Comment: This is within a class called Config. So I use it this way:
echo Config::findKey('Key', $array);

Comment: replace self::findKey($key, $item); with $this->findKey($key, $item);

Comment: That did not work. It says **Using $this when not in object context**.

Comment: Please edit your question and show whole class code.

Comment: It's nothing more in that class at the moment, but what I failed to add is static, which still doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your method recursively, and return a value at the deepest level, but you forgot to pass the return value back up the recursion tree.

So change this:

```
                self::findKey($key, $item);
```

by:

```
                $result = self::findKey($key, $item);
                if ($result !== false) {
                    return $result;
                }
```

.. and make sure you return `false` upon failure to find the key, after the `forEach` loop:

```
class Config
{   
    public static function findKey($key, $array) {
        foreach($array as $item) {
            if(is_array($item)) {
                if(isset($item[$key])) {
                    return $item[$key];
                } else {
                    $result = self::findKey($key, $item);
                    if ($result !== false) {
                        return $result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't change anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

findKey - non static method. You should write

```
public static function findKey($key, $array){}
```

before foreach loop make check is $array and not empty

this method only return result, for print you should call `echo ClassName::findKey($key, $array)`

Comment: I had public static before, still no difference.

Comment: after end foreach write some like return $key . ' not found';

Comment: Yep, that says not found.